# Can a thread be suspended by scheduler before first instruction in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

In Java, can a thread be suspended by the scheduler before the execution of the first instruction? So, the actual parameters are already set, but the first instruction of the method is not yet called? For example:

```
void method(int value) {
    // [1]
    int otherValue = otherMethod(value);
}
```

So, can the thread be suspended at [1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. At that place there are assembly instructions even if you don't see them.

Let's take this code for example:

```
private void method(final int value) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This yields the following bytecode:

```
  // access flags 0x2
  private method(I)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ILOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 9 L1
    RETURN
```

So a thread executing this bytecode could be for example suspended at `GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;`, which is effectively **before** the actual call you can see in the Java code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. Why wouldn't it? Moreover `[1]` is not really the first instruction that is executed by the underlying native thread, so we can treat `[1]` just as every other operation. There's nothing special about it actually.

Answer (score 0):

A Thread can be taken out of the Running state at any time by the Thread Scheduler.
Check out the allowed java.lang.Thread.States in the API, and this useful [State Transition Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html).

You can never rely on a sequence of execution with Threads, unless you have properly encoded that sequence (e.g. using synchronized. join, etc.)

To quote the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html):

> These semantics do not prescribe how a multithreaded program should be executed. Rather, they describe the behaviors that multithreaded programs are allowed to exhibit. Any execution strategy that generates only allowed behaviors is an acceptable execution strategy.